# Unable to click an elemt " Search Intimation View-Details" thows not such element Exception

Tags: selenium, testing, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests, vaadin

I am new to selenium,Guys please help me to click this element " Search Intimation View-Details".Cant able to use the ID has it is in number,& class name is not pointing exactly to that button.Guide me please,I'm strucked up.I tried 
driver.findElementByXPath(" //div[span='Search Intimation View-Details'] ").click();
    //
driver.findElementByClassName("v-tree-node v-tree-node-expanded v-tree-node-root v-tree-node-last ").click();

Below is the code

```
<div class="v-tree-node v-tree-node-expanded v-tree-node-last" id="gwt-uid-36" role="treeitem" aria-selected="false" aria-labelledby="gwt-uid-35" aria-level="2" aria-expanded="true">
<div class="v-tree-node-caption">
<div id="gwt-uid-35" for="gwt-uid-36">
<span>Intimations</span>
</div>
</div>
<div class="v-tree-node-children v-tree-node-children-last" role="group">
<div class="v-tree-node v-tree-node-leaf v-tree-node-leaf-last" id="gwt-uid-38" role="treeitem" aria-selected="true" aria-labelledby="gwt-uid-37" aria-level="3">
<div class="v-tree-node-caption v-tree-node-selected">
<div id="gwt-uid-37" for="gwt-uid-38">
<span>Search Intimation View-Details</span>
</div>
</div>
<div class="v-tree-node-children v-tree-node-children-last" role="group"></div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you are using Java selenium binding, so Use this code

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[normalize-space()='Search Intimation View-Details']")).click()
```

Answer (score 0):

The below script uses the Java programming language and uses the `CSS` locators to find the required element if we are unable to find using the class, id, XPath, etc.

Use:

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div[role=treeitem][id^='gwt-uid-36']")).click();
```